# Using multiple classes java

Tags: java

I would like to know how to use multiples clas in Java. I know how use method from other class and also constructors but i would like know how create a new "object" for example. If i am making a PersonDirectory, then i can have class called Person which has the attributes Name and Age. Then i want to make a Person[] in my PersonDirectory Class and add names and ages to it. How can i do that? I have some code that i did, but it doesn't seem to work out.

```
import java.io.*;

public class PersonDirectory {

    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    static Person[] personArray = new Person[2];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        for (int i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the name of the person: ");
            String name = br.readLine();
            System.out.print("Please enter the age of the person: ");
            int age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            personArray[i] = new Person(name,age);
        }

        for(Person p : personArray) {
            System.out.println("The name is "+p.getName()+" and the age is "+p.getAge());
        }

    }
}
```

second class

```
public class Person {

    private static String name = "";
    private static int age = 0;

    public Person(String name,int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public static int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt seem to work, what is going wrong, does it compile ok? are you getting errors/warnings, if so what are they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the properties in the `Person` class are static. Static means that they are shared between all object(instances). Remove the static keyword from the `Person` class and you will be fine.

Comment: when print out Person[0] it give me something very odd.

Comment: never mind. Thanks, i also noticed you needed to get rid of private.

Comment: @user681159: There is no reason to remove any `private` from the code in the question.